# Shape factor of two concentric shells

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-radiation, steady-state

So I was understanding the concept of shape factor when I came upon the classic shape factor of two concentric shells problem. It was simple if you would apply the reciprocity theorem and get that the shape factor of the bigger shell (Radius $R_2$, Area $A_2$ 4π${R_2}^{2}$) with respect to the smaller shell (Radius $R_1$, Area $A_1$ 4π${R_1}^{2}$) is $\frac{{R_1}^2}{{R_2^2}}$.
But what if we try to do it by another approach, which my professor followed. Say you have both of the shells at the same temperature T and the outer surrounding is also at a temperature T.[image] He said that the outer shell will now be in equilibrium with the surroundings and inner shell and has reached steady state. So heat gained by it is = heat lost by it. This means (only the inner shell provides it with radiation heat current = σ$A_1$$T^4$, the surrounding is at the same temperature so there will be no heat lost to it, and if the shape factor is f, then heat lost to the inner shell by the outer shell is fσ$A_2$$T^4$) that fσ$A_2$$T^4$ = σ$A_1$$T^4$. Thus $A_1$ = f$A_2$, thus f =  $\frac{{R_1}^2}{{R_2^2}}$. Now, as shape factor is only dependent on geometry of the two surfaces and independent of the temperatures of the setup, so this shape factor is the shape factor that we previously needed to calculate.

But my question is that why is it necessary for the block to be at equilibrium when the outside temperature is T only? Why can't the temperature of the outer surrounding be $\frac{T}{2}$ (case a), $\frac{{R_1}T}{{R_2}}$, or any arbitrary value when the block remains in equilibrium. I am not entirely satisfied with the answer that it the surrounding temperature is not T then the block will have to lose heat, because is it not possible for the inner shell heat current (that reaches the outer shell) to compensate for the heat loss to the surroundings; but then we get some different value of view factor (like when we have the equilibrium state as case a : f will come out to be $\frac {A_1}{A_2}$ - $\frac {1}{16}$ or case b : f will come out to be $\frac {A_1}{A_2}$ - $\frac {{R_1}^{4}}{{R_2}^{4}}$ and all other possible cases)?